# Can I manipulate .csv files without reading them into memory?

Tags: r, csv

I have an 8GB .csv file. I have tried to read it into R in various ways (`read.csv`, `fread`), but am receiving an error message: `could not allocate memory in C function.` The file has 200,000 lines and about a thousand columns.

I can however use `readLines` or the `nrows` argument of `read.csv()` to see the variable names in the file and the way the data is structured.

If I know which variables I need (let's say they are `weight`, `height` and `age` in the .csv), is it possible to filter the .csv based on those variables and write the filtered data to a new (and smaller) .csv without reading the full data into memory?

I am working in a restrictive virtual environment so use of other database tools or methods is challenging. A solution based entirely on R is desirable if possible.

I don't believe a full MRE is possible for this question given its nature, but if you wanted a dummy dataset for demonstration purposes I have included one below. In this example data, I would be looking to select just the age, weight and height columns and write them to a new .csv.

```
structure(list(name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve"), 
               age = c(33, 50, 29, 40, 55), 
               weight = c(72, 85, 65, 77, 94), 
               height = c(172, 187, 154, 198, 162), 
               sex = c("Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male")), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: `fread(<file>, select = c("weight", "height", "age"))` ?

Comment: Depending on your operating system it might be easier to use another tool. For example if you can run `cut` in a terminal: `cut -d, -f 2,3,4 data.csv > new.csv`. [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) might be another option.

Comment: OP did say "solution based entirely on R is desirable if possible" ...

Comment: Is using the `arrow` package an option? It is designed for use with larger than memory datasets.

Comment: Use [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `col_select` argument of `vroom::vroom`:

> `col_select`: Columns to include in the results. You can use the same
> mini-language as ‘dplyr::select()’ to refer to the columns by
> name. Use ‘c()’ to use more than one selection expression.
> Although this usage is less common, ‘col_select’ also accepts
> a numeric column index. See ‘?tidyselect::language’ for full
> details on the selection language.

```r
dd <- structure(list(name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve"), 
               age = c(33, 50, 29, 40, 55), 
               weight = c(72, 85, 65, 77, 94), 
               height = c(172, 187, 154, 198, 162), 
               sex = c("Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male")), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
write.csv(dd, "tmp.csv")
vroom::vroom("tmp.csv", col_select = c("weight", "height", "age"))
```

@hugh points out that `data.table::fread()` also has this capability:

```r
data.table::fread("tmp.csv", select = c("weight", "height", "age"))
```

both `vroom` and `data.table::fread` are very fast as well: e.g. see benchmarks [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vroom/vignettes/benchmarks.html)

For writing data back out to a delimited file (if you really want to do that ...) these packages have `?vroom::vroom_write` and `data.table::fwrite`